# Группировка и сортировка в DQL Doctrine по дате.

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS Cnt, user.name, DATE( office.created_at ) AS Date 
FROM office, user 
WHERE user.group_id =1 
AND created_by = user.id 
GROUP BY user.name, DATE( office.created_at ) 
ORDER BY user.name, DATE( office.created_at )
```

Как переписать MySQL запрос на DQL Doctrine?

Comment: Функции DATE нет в нативном dql. Попробуйте заменить на `CAST(office.created_at as date)`. Не называйте поле `Date`. К тому же в группировке и сортировке лучше указывать имя поля вместо функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если никакой динамики не нужно, то замените значения на параметры, функцию DATE можно попробовать заменить функцией [SUBSTRING](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions). В [документации](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) очень неплохо все написано. Если нужно динамично добавлять\убирать условия нужно копать в сторону [ExpressionBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class).